# configuration.php unwritable when permission is 0644 but writable when 0664

Tags: joomla-3.x, configuration, file-permissions

My Joomla is 3.9.4. When I tried to make some global configuration change in the backend, I got this error:

> Could not write to the configuration file.

I looked at the file system, configuration.php has the right owner and is set to `0644`, and I can make changes to it via FTP.

I then tried setting the permission to `0777`, it is writable; then I tried `0666` and `0664` and it is also good.

Only when I set it to `0644` do I get the above error. I've never encountered this kind of problem before. I suspect it is something wrong with my server(I host the website on a VPS on linode), but I couldn't figure out.

What could possibly be wrong?

**UPDATE**
I found some more clues. This website was duplicated from another server where the website ran well. When I look both site's FPA, I found that on the problematic server, the permission section is like
[image]

While on the other server, it is
[image]

I don't understand how come one is writable whereas the other is not while both permissions are 0755.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here, need to set php running mode to FastCGI: https://docs.joomla.org/Why_can%27t_you_install_any_extensions%3F#File_ownership_advice_from_ianmac

Comment: please accept your answer so that the system stops bumping it.